# Compare modification time of file with given time stamps?

Tags: c++, bash, shell, awk, gawk

I have a hdfs dir with lots of files and directory in it in following format.

```
-rw-rw-rw-   3 root xyz  <filesize> 2015-04-12 00:34 file1
-rw-rw-rw-   3 root xyz  <filesize> 2015-04-11 11:34 file2
-rw-rw-rw-   3 root xyz  <filesize> 2015-04-09 09:54 file3
drwxrwxrwx   3 root xyz    0        2015-04-02 00:34 dir
```

I've one awk script which filters the files from the list using

```
awk '{ if($1 !~ /d.*/ ) {print $0}}'.
```

I am using this in c++ function which has two timestamps in `date(yyyy-mm-dd)` and `time (hh:mm:ss)` format.
I would like to put condition in 'if' of 'awk' which can filter the files which lies between two timestamps.

I tried doing

`($6 >= startDate) && ($6 <= endDate) && ($7 >= startTime) && ($7 <= endTime)`,

but this is not working as expected. I am newbie to awk.

Comment: Why are you doing all that in awk if you're running C++ code? Just do it directly in C++. (And [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).)

Comment: The directory is in hdfs file s/m not in my local file system, and moreover the legacy reason, let me know if u have any suggestion on how to do it using awk/gawk.

Comment: So? If you can access it in your shell, you can access it in C++. Or C. Or anything else.

Comment: but then I need to write another function/c++ code which will recursively explore the given directory. Is it worth doing ?

Comment: Note that `awk '{ if($1 !~ /d.*/ ) {print $0}}'.` can be rewritten more awk-ishly as `awk '$1 !~ /d/'` (the `.*` is doing absolutely nothing for your regexp) or even just `awk '!/^d/'` but then you have to wonder why you're using awk at all instead of just `grep -v '^d'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to simplify this.

```
find . -newermt "$dt1" ! -newermt "$dt2"
```

Here is a shell script, which i used to test. If you can pass the arguments from within your C++ code, you can shorten this to a one liner with just the find command.

```
# Date 1
startDate=2015-04-11
startTime=21:10:00
dt1="$startDate $startTime"

# Date 2
endDate=2015-04-11
endTime=22:10:00
dt2="$endDate $endTime"
find . -newermt "$dt1" ! -newermt "$dt2"
```

Note: I assume, startdate and starttime go together and enddate and endtime go together. But you have the freedom to choose otherwise.

Comment: I cant use "find" since there is no "find" command in java shell for hdfs.